# Combine two audios

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have two audio files (`input0.mp3` and `input1.mp3`). First file must be the background audio (with `0.1` - `0.3` volume) — and if second audio will be longer, then first audio must infinite loop. First audio must be overlaid by the second.

[This example](https://superuser.com/questions/1089843/ffmpeg-combine-two-or-three-audios-into-one-by-lowering-the-volume-of-the-othe/1089885#1089885) has very difficult ffmpeg code.

I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp3 -i input1.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]asetpts=N/SR/TB,volume=0.1[s2];[0]asetpts=N/SR/TB[s3];[s2][s3]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[b];[b]amix[a]" -map "[a]" mixed.mp3
```

But I broked the code of example above :(
If infinite looping of background audio is impossible, I need at least combining of two audios and decreasing the volume of first.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i second.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=bg.mp3:loop=0,volume=0.3,asetpts=N/SR/TB[bg];[bg][0]amix=duration=shortest" mixed.mp3
```

The amovie source filter loads the background music and loops it indefinitely. The amix filter mixes the audio till second.mp3 ends.